# Python setuptools ask for unittest and unittest ask for setuptools

Tags: python

I'm working on AIX and I'm trying to install beaver or any other log snipper.
The problem is when I'm trying to run them I'm asked to install other packages like setuptools
and unittest.

I can't manged to install those because its look like They depend on each other.
When I'm trying to install setuptools I'm geting "ImportError: No module named unittest" and when trying to install unittest I'm getting ImportError: No module named setuptools"

Anyone know how it can be solved ?

Regards,

Yaniv.

Comment: How are you trying to install these?

Comment: `unittest` is in the python standard library.  is your python too old?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5 and i'm trying to install them using python setup.py installl